# Pass array to val in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a problem to set the selected Values of my "Select2".
When I pass the id values separated by commas it works. But if the pass like array doesn't work.

this is my Select

```
<select class="form-control" id="myselect" multiple="multiple">
<option id="1">Value1</option>
<option id="2">Value2</option>
<option id="3">Value3</option>
<option id="4">Value4</option>
<option id="5">Value5</option>
</select>
```

It works

```
$("#myselect").select2().select2('val', [1,2,3]);
```

but this dosn't work

```
var array_selection = [1,2,3];
$("#myselect").select2().select2('val', [array_selection]);
```

Comment: What's your definition of `$.fn.select2` ? Ah, I see, it's from a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting your `array_selection` Array into another Array. Change

```
var array_selection = [1,2,3];
$("#myselect").select2().select2('val', [array_selection]);
```

to

```
var array_selection = [1,2,3];
$("#myselect").select2().select2('val', array_selection);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding `.trigger('change')` after set value `$("#myselect").select2().select2('val', array_selection).trigger('change');` will works

Or like this

```
var array_selection = [1,2,3];
$("#myselect").select2().val(array_selection).trigger('change');
```