# Laravel 5.8 and Select2 function not working

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent, jquery-select2

I am trying to implement a feature from Select2 in my Laravel recipe application. I have a tags system in place for my recipes. When I go and edit my recipes, I want the current tags to show up in the select field. To do this, I am using jQuery from the Select2 documentation. Everything seems to be fine and there are no errors, but it is not returning the information that I want. Can somebody see where there is an error?

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $recipe = Recipe::find($id);
        $tags = Tag::pluck('name', 'id');

        return view('recipes.edit')->with('recipe', $recipe)->with('tags', $tags);
    }
```

**View**

```
            <fieldset>
                    <small class="errorMessage"></small>
                    <label for="tags">Tags</label>
                    <select class="select2-multi" name="tags[]" id="tagsList" multiple="multiple">
                      @foreach($tags as $id => $name)
                            <option value="{{$id}}">{{$name}}</option>
                       @endforeach
                    </select>
            </fieldset>
```

**jQuery script**

```
<script>
    $('.select2-multi').select2().val({!! json_encode($recipe->tags()->pluck('tag_id')->toArray()) !!}).trigger('change');
</script>
```

It seems to run just fine, it's just not returning anything from my DB. I know you guys don't have my database tables and columns in front of you, but I have triple checked these and it all matches up as it should. Thanks!

Comment: I think your logic `.val([])` is incorrect. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838578/pass-array-to-val-in-select2 Shows that to set val of `multiple` array, you need to do `.select2().select2('val', array);`, or maybe `.select2({ val: array });`?

Comment: I don't understand why you are data passing to the Select2 when init it? I think you don't need to pass any value when Select2 init. You already fill into the Select2 via ``@foreach``

Comment: @FGDeveloper As far as I see the `@foreach` renders all possible options, while `val()` sets the currently selected items.

Comment: @Thomas Which can be done in the `@foreach`, with `{{ in_array($id, $tagIds) ? 'selected' : '' }}` (don't have a `$tagIds`, but you get the gist), which begs the question; why bother with the `.val()` at all?

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use JS to set the value? If not, you could @Tim Lewis's method. Otherwise please post the generated jQuery script.

Comment: @TimLewis yes you were right. Thank you for directing me to that other question. The .val([]) logic was not correct!

Comment: No worries. Gonna mark this as a duplicate. Or, you can add an answer on how you accomplished this if it's different. (Possible duplicate of [Pass array to val in Select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838578/pass-array-to-val-in-select2))

Comment: Hmm, probably best to mark this as a duplicate! @TimLewis